# OpenCV cannot be imported to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I am a beginner for android development and OpenCV. I need to import OpenCV to my Android Studio project. I followed some introduction given by stackoverflow, but still I cannot import it.

1. I downloaded OpenCV-4.1.0-android-sdk
2. Then unzip it and started to import it
3. file->new->import module-> selected path

But, after completed step 03 "Next" and "Finish" button are not visible

[import module from source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVC93.png)

I need to start this.Please help me...

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to just use the top level directory and not the sdk directory?

Comment: Actually, I didn't try this. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: In your screenshot you have it going to `OpenCv-android-sdk\sdk`. Try and just go to `OpenCv-android-sdk` and see if that works fro you.

Comment: I trried it also.but it didn't work. It shows a error "specify location of the gradle or android eclipse project"